# Github Self-hosted runner not getting latest version of code

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I have self-hosted runner with the below yml file. Everything runs successfully, but when I ssh into the server and cd to the application directory, the code is one commit behind the main branch. If I run `git pull`, it pulls the latest commit. Here is my configuration file:

```
name: Build and Deploy
on: push
jobs:
  Deploy-on-local-runner:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: run npm ci
        run: npm ci
      - name: npm run build
        run: npm run build
```

I made the change that VonC recommended and it does not appear to have any change in the code. I updated the yml file and changed a test.txt file, and the action ran successfully but did not update the files on disk on the server. When I SSH'd in to the box and ran `git pull` this is what I received in response:

```
kevin@machine:~/projects/project$ git pull
remote: Enumerating objects: 11, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (11/11), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1/1), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 2), reused 6 (delta 2), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), 449 bytes | 64.00 KiB/s, done.
From github.com:user/repo
   bc759e9..1e4b98e  main       -> origin/main
Updating bc759e9..1e4b98e
Fast-forward
 .github/workflows/deploy.yml | 3 +++
 test.txt                     | 2 +-
 2 files changed, 4 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

Answer (score 0):

As noted in [`actions/checkout` issues](https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/439#issuecomment-965968956)

> You can use the ref attribute to point to a specific branch.
> This way subsequent jobs always pull the latest code from that branch, and not from the revision that started the workflow.

If the problem is that it (the `actions/checkout`) does not fetch the full commit history, add a `fetch-depth: 0`

```yaml
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          ref: main
```

Comment: Hi VonC - I've just attempted your change, and it did not update my test.txt file. When I manually ran ```git pull``` it updated correctly (as noted in my question).

Comment: @Kevin OK, it was worth a shot. Not sure why the latest from that branch is not pulled though.